# making a comfortable php multidimensional array from database

Tags: php, arrays, loops

i got a code like this:

```
include 'dbconnect.php';
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;"); 

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * From courseEnglish");
$courseInfo = array();


while ($row_course = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
   $courseInfo[] = $row_course;
```

it gives me a php array from the db, but  in order to present the data i need to use:

```
echo $courseInfo[2]['Course'];
```

i would like for the array to be so i can just type somthing like:

```
echo $courseInfo[2][2];
```

is there an option for changing the code so ill have an array i can loop on with just indexes?

Comment: mysql_fetch_row($sql);

Comment: I doubt you really need it. 'Course' is way more comfortable than just numeric index. May be you need just a different loop operator, `foreach`

Comment: Aside: `$sql` isn't an ideal variable name for a result resource - that would generally be for SQL strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're looking for `mysql_fetch_row`, which does the same as `mysql_fetch_assoc`, except for the fact that it returns a numerically indexed array. [here's the link to the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php).

Having said that, you might want to consider ditching the deprecated `mysql_*` extension, in favour of either `mysqli_*` (the `i` stands for improved), or the fully OO-style `PDO` extension. Check the red box at the top of any `mysql_*` function's manual page, it contains links to the preferred counterpart-function...

But all things considered, looking at your query (`SELECT * FROM ...`), I'd *not* use a numerically indexed array at all to get the results. If your table contains more than 1 field, you'll hit trouble sooner or later, when trying to work out what piece of data is coming from what field. Seriously... just use an assoc array, or even better: use objects.
Suppose you change the table layout (add/remove certain fields?), it'll be hell to maintain your code in that case. Still, it's up to you to decide, but I thought I'd might mention this.

Comment: Yep. Use `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this..?

```
foreach ($courseInfo as $course_index = > $course_content)
   foreach ($course_content as $field)
     echo $field;
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
while ($row_course = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
```